# Targeting DOM elements from parent to grand parent produces different result

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to target 3 buttons as in the image below

[image]

Here is the code for each thumbnail

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="product-image">
        <img src="./images/raspberry.jpg" alt="Raspberry - 1/4 Kg">
    </div>
    <h4 class="product-name">Raspberry - 1/4 Kg</h4>
    <p class="product-price">160</p>
    <div class="stepper-input">
        <a href="#" class="decrement">–</a>
        <input type="number" class="quantity" value="1">
        <a href="#" class="increment">+</a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-action">
        <button class="" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try the following code below it fulfills the goal of clicking the 3 buttons

```
add_cart_btn_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='product'] button")
add_cart_btn_link = driver.find_elements(*add_cart_btn_locator)

for i in add_cart_btn_link:
    i.click()
```

But when I try to change my selector to `div[class='product-action'] button`, only the **first button is clicked** then the below error appears

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

May I kindly ask what is the difference of the two locators and why they do not work identically?

Answer (score 1):

change your loop :

```
add_cart_btn_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='product-action'] button")
add_cart_btn_link = driver.find_elements(*add_cart_btn_locator)
nbrlinks = len(add_cart_btn_link)
for i in range(nbrlinks):
    add_cart_btn_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='product-action'] button")
    add_cart_btn_link = driver.find_elements(*add_cart_btn_locator)
    add_cart_btn_link[i].click()
```

you have to reload the search of items each time

Comment: Tried the code you recommended but seems I still get the  `element is not attached to the page document` error message. Seems the loop can't find the 2nd button

Comment: i dont see why... all is reloaded, what is the url? and you say Seems... are you sure its not at another place of code? you have to do samething with other loops of same type